# understanding spritz.js design pattern

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to understand the design pattern of spritz.js , its a plugin written by john resing ::

```
/* Simple JavaScript Inheritance
 * By John Resig http://ejohn.org/
 * MIT Licensed.
 */
// Inspired by base2 and Prototype
(function(){
  var initializing = false, fnTest = /xyz/.test(function(){xyz;}) ? /\b_super\b/ : /.*/;
  // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
  this.Class = function(){};

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype;
    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing  = true;
    var prototype = new this();
    initializing  = false;

    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for (var name in prop) {
      // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
        typeof _super[name] == "function" && fnTest.test(prop[name]) ?
        (function(name, fn){
          return function() {
            var tmp = this._super;

            // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
            // but on the super-class
            this._super = _super[name];

            // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
            // remove it when we're done executing
            var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
            this._super = tmp;

            return ret;
          };
        })(name, prop[name]) :
        prop[name];
    }

    // The dummy class constructor
    function Class() {
      // All construction is actually done in the init method
      if ( !initializing && this.init )
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;

    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.prototype.constructor = Class;

    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;

    return Class;
  };
})();

/*!
 * jQuery Sprite Plugin v0.1
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Justen
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function( $ ) {

    var SpriteSheet = function(json){

        var frames = [];

        this.currentFrame = 1;
        this.totalFrames = 1;
        this.frame = null;
        this.change = function(){};

        this.__construct__ = function(json){
            this.parse(json);
        }

        this.gotoFrame = function(int){

            if(this.frames.length > 0){

                var f = Math.max(1, Math.min(this.totalFrames, int));

                if(f !== this.currentFrame){

                    this.currentFrame = f;
                    this.frame = this.frames[f - 1];
                    this.change();
                }
            }
        }

        this.parse = function(data){

            this.frames = [];
            this.totalFrames = data.frames.count;
            this.currentFrame = 1;

            var cols = data.width / data.frames.width;
            var rows = data.height / data.frames.height;

            if(rows > 0 || cols > 0){
                for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                    for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){

                        if(this.frames.length == data.frames.count){

                            break;

                        }else{

                            var frame = {
                                x: j * data.frames.width,
                                y: i * data.frames.height,
                                width: data.frames.width,
                                height: data.frames.height
                            };

                            this.frames.push(frame);
                        }
                    }
                }

                this.frame = this.frames[0];
            }

            this.gotoFrame(1);
        }

        this.__construct__(json);
    }

    // STAGE ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var Stage = (function(){

        var instance;

        function __construct__(){

            this.items = [];
            this.tickInterval = setInterval($.proxy(enterFrame, this), 32);
            //this.tickInterval = setInterval($.proxy(enterFrame, this), 200);

            return {
                add: function(obj){
                    add(obj);
                }
            }
        };

        function enterFrame(){

            for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
                this.items[i].render();
            }
        };

        function add(obj){

            //be sure the object registering has the
            //appropriate handler

            if(obj.render){
            this.items.push(obj);

            }else{
                throw 'Missing render on object register.';
            }
        };

        return {

            getInstance: function(){
                if (!instance)
                    instance = __construct__();

                return instance;
            }
        }
    })();

    // MOVIECLIP ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var MovieClip = Class.extend({

        currentFrame: 1,
        totalFrames: 1,

        init: function(json){

            this.stage = Stage.getInstance().add(this);
            this.sprite = new SpriteSheet(json);
            this.totalFrames = this.sprite.totalFrames;
            this._isPlaying = false;
            this._targetFrame = -1;
            this.update = function(){};
        },

        render: function(){

            this.currentFrame = this.sprite.currentFrame;

            //check to see if there is a new frame waiting
            //to be rendered before just playing the next
            //frame in the sequence.

            if(this._targetFrame != -1){

                this.sprite.gotoFrame(this._targetFrame);
                this._targetFrame = -1;

            }else{

                if(this._isPlaying)
                    this.sprite.gotoFrame(this.currentFrame + 1);
            }


            //this is the lamest thing... I trigger our callback
            //at the end of the enter, should be more like Flash with
            //events that support multiple listeners...

            this.update();
        },

        play: function(){
            this._isPlaying = true;
        },

        stop: function(){
            this._isPlaying = false;
        },

        nextFrame: function(){
            this._targetFrame = this.sprite.currentFrame + 1;
        },

        prevFrame: function(){
            this._targetFrame = this.sprite.currentFrame - 1;
        },

        gotoAndPlay: function(int){
            this._targetFrame = int;
            this.play();
        },

        gotoAndStop: function(int){
            this._targetFrame = int;
            this.stop();
        },
    });

    var Spritz = MovieClip.extend({

        el: null,

        init: function(el, json){
            this._super(json);
            this.el = el;
            this.el.css('background-size', json.width + 'px' + ' ' + json.height + 'px');
            this.el.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
            this.el.css('background-position', '0 0');

            this.render();
        },

        render: function(){

            this._super();

            var tx = -this.sprite.frame.x + 'px';
            var ty = -this.sprite.frame.y + 'px';

            //TODO add support for changing texture based
            //on frame data.
            this.el.css('background-position', tx + ' ' + ty)
        }
    })

    var PlayOnce = Spritz.extend({

        stopMe: false,

        render: function(){

            this._super();

            switch(this.sprite.currentFrame){

                case 1:

                    if(this.stopMe){
                        this.stopMe = false;
                        this.stop(true);
                    }

                    break;

                case this.sprite.totalFrames:

                    this.gotoAndPlay(1);
                    break;
            }
        },

        stop: function(stopImmediatly){
            if(!stopImmediatly) {
                this.stopMe = true;
            }else{
                this._super();
            }
        }
    })

    // PLUGIN //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $.fn.spritz = function(json){

        this.mc = new PlayOnce(this, json);

        this.play = function(){
            this.mc.play();
            this.mc.stop();
        }

        return this;
    };

})( jQuery );
```

now what is the below for ::

```
  this.Class = function(){};

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
```

what is the purpose of `this.class = function(){}` ?

also what is `Class.extend = function(prop) {` ?

later on in the plugin there is code attached to Class , like so ::

```
Class.prototype = prototype;

// Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
```

now in the past I have seen plugins written, like so ::

```
var gallery = function() {
      //
}

gallery.prototype.something = function() {
      //
}

gallery.prototype.someOtherFunction = function() {
      // 
}
```

is this plugin following a similar design pattern or is it something different ? I am basically just trying to understand what design pattern this plugin is following .

So once again to be specific and repeat my question what is the below code for and how is it being used ::

```
  this.Class = function(){};

  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super    = this.prototype;
```

?

Comment: You will want to read http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ - there he does introduce that `Class` thing. spritz.js just uses it to declare its classes - and you're right, it could've been written in the traditional way as well.

Comment: In short, it's not a design pattern, it's just syntactic sugar, and does the same.